# Attributes handover from TelnetServer to TelnetServerHandler netty-4.0.10 Final

Tags: java, netty

I have the plan to read my config file in the server part into the memory and use the data in the handler.

Attached the code snippets.

// from the example directory

```
public class TelnetServer {

    private final int port;
    private final String myConfFile;

    // MyConf is a singleton class which read the config
    // from my app into memory
    private static final AttributeKey<MyConf> myCAttribute = new AttributeKey<MyConf>("MyConf");

    public TelnetServer(int port,String confFile) {
        this.port = port;
        this.myConfFile = confFile;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.childAttr(myCAttribute, MyConf.getInstance(myConfFile));
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new TelnetServerInitializer());

            b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the value in the TelnetServerHandler.

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String request) throws Exception {

    // Generate and write a response.
    String response;
    boolean close = false;
    if (request.isEmpty()) {
        response = "Please type something.\r\n";
    } else if ("bye".equals(request.toLowerCase())) {
        response = "Have a good day!\r\n";
        close = true;
    } else {
        response = "Did you say '" + request + "'?\r\n";
        MyConf mc = (MyConf)ctx.attr("MyConf");            
    }

    // We do not need to write a ChannelBuffer here.
    // We know the encoder inserted at TelnetPipelineFactory will do the conversion.
    ChannelFuture future = ctx.write(response);

    // Close the connection after sending 'Have a good day!'
    // if the client has sent 'bye'.
    if (close) {
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't works.
Please can anybody point me to the right doc or give me a hint how I can realize this plan.

Thanks for help.
John

Comment: Are you sure `MyConf.getInstance(myConfFile)` returns a non-null value?

Comment: Also you can attach a remote debugger (e.g. eclipse) to inspect ctx. Based on http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html#175 - I would expect your code to work...

Comment: @Nino: Yes, the instance have content. If not I throw a NPE, due tot the fact that without data the server can't do nothing.

Sorry, looks like I have asked wrong.

The question should be.

Must I also add a

`private static final AttributeKey<MyConf> myCAttribute = new AttributeKey<MyConf>("MyConf");`

into the TelnetServerHandler, due to the fact that when I add the line

MyConf mc = ctx.attr("MyConf");

I get the error

**The method attr(AttributeKey<T>) in the type AttributeMap is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Thanks for help John

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
MyConf mc = ctx.attr(TelnetServer.myCAttribute).get();
```

I tried it in my project and had problems getting the attribute from the channel context and had to get in from the channel itself:

```
MyConf mc = ctx.channel().attr(TelnetServer.myCAttribute).get();
```

Try if one of those work for you.

Comment: Dear Moh-Aw, thanks for your input I have now the following solution. In **TelnetServer** `public static AttributeKey<MyConf> getMycattribute() {
  return myCAttribute;
 }` and in **TelnetServerHandler** `MyConf mc = (MyConf) ctx.channel().attr(TelnetServer.getMycattribute()).get();` . I'am not sure if **...ctx.attr(...** also works.